# format decimals javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, formatting

I have strings of numbers...

`**[0.7955635, 485, .421, 1.08]**`

Assuming i have a jquery selector for this collection, how would I format them to always show a leading zero (or integer) followed by two decimal places: **[0.79, 485.00, 0.42, 1.08]**.

Comment: When you say "strings of numbers" are they strings or numbers? What you have written is an array literal (more or less) containing numbers, not strings.

Comment: strings, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It is usual to only format numbers for output, formatting usually involves rounding so do it permaturely may introduce unwanted errors or inaccuracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example -

```
var data = [0.7955635, 485, .421, 1.08];

$(data).each(function(index, value){
    alert(parseFloat(value).toFixed(2));
})
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/vnW7H/